# How do I vertically center text in a Beamer frame with no title?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I want to have a plain Beamer frame with no title and some vertically and horizontally centered, prominent text. The following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
  \begin{center}
    Thank you
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces the following result

[image]

where the text is clearly closer to the top of the frame than to the bottom. However, if I add a title (made invisible but still occupying vertical and horizontal space using the `\phantom` command to clearly show the different vertical positioning of the body text) as follows

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{\phantom{Title}}
  \begin{center}
    Thank you
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the text seems to be (closer to being) vertically centered:

[image]

I would expect the body text of a plain frame with no title and an optional `c` argument to be perfectly vertically centered – and not the other way around. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Preferably, solutions would not resort to using external packages such as TikZ; I hope that the `beamer` class provides a simple solution to this – in my opinion – basic problem of perfectly aligning the body text on a presentation slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tikz to position your text with respect to the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[lightgray] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
\draw[lightgray] (current page.south east) -- (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {Thank you};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use the `[s]`tretchable frame option (needs beamer v3.65 or newer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[lightgray] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
\draw[lightgray] (current page.south east) -- (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[s]
\vfill

\centering Thank you

\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could redefine the `[c]entred` frameoption to have the same stretchability on top and bottom:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[lightgray] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
\draw[lightgray] (current page.south east) -- (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
\centering Thank you
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The `[s]`tretchable option is exactly what I was looking for. I modified my question to favor solutions that do not use external packages, since I think that this behavior should be achievable in a relatively straightforward way using the `beamer` document class only. For older Beamer versions or more advanced alignment, TikZ is definitely also an option to consider.